# Questions about adding vanilla

Tags: flavor

I'm on my third brew. 
Midwest brewing irish red in bottles
Midwest brewing brown nut ale in secondary

Just bought Brewers Best milk stout.

I pretty much wanted to be a little creative without going overboard and do an all grain recipe.

So I am looking for a little help. I want this to be a vanilla stout so I guess in this case it will be a vanilla milk stout.

Should I use vanilla beans or vanilla extract?
How much?
Should I use in the boil or in the secondary?
Has anyone used vanilla paste instead of vanilla beans or vanilla extract?

If you could walk me through this a little bit again only my 3rd brew! I don't even know if my other ones turned out haha. I have tasted them along the way and they taste fine but I won't be satisfied until I drink a fully carbed beer and get a buzz!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've had good luck ordering whole beans pretty cheap from this site: http://www.myspicesage.com/vanilla.html  And per the answer from Denny, just slice them in half, scrap out the goo (smells soooo good), and throw it all into the fermentor.

Answer (score 6):

It may be too much information, but here's an excerpt from my upcoming book "Experimental Brewing"...

> Vanilla can be used in several different forms.  Start by obtaining
>   the best vanilla you can find, whether it’s vanilla beans or extract. 
>   Beans should be moist, pliable, fat, and “juicy”.  Extract should not
>   have any fake aromas or flavors to it.  Some extracts are made with
>   wood byproducts.  Although some of these may be good, a lot of them
>   are not.   Do some research and be prepared to audition different
>   forms from different sources to make your choice. Be careful as some
>   extracts of dubious quality use the tonka bean, which, in addition to
>   vanilla, also provides coumarin, a powerful liver toxin. We recommend
>   that you buy beans online because they are generally cheaper and
>   higher quality than anything you’ll find in the grocery store. Another
>   bonus, you can also usually find “Grade B” beans, which aren’t as
>   pretty as “Grade A”, but work dandy. They’re also a lot cheaper,
>   usually around 1/3rd the price! Bourbon Vanilla: When you think
>   vanilla, this is the flavor that you think of. It’s a big potent blast
>   of vanillin, the main active flavorant associated with vanilla. The
>   bold character makes it perfect for anything that you want people to
>   smell and taste and immediately say “VANILLA!” Historical note: The
>   Bourbon name has nothing to do with Bourbon whiskey. Both Bourbon
>   County, Kentucky and Bourbon Island (aka Réunion Island off the coast
>   of Madgascar) get their name from the French Royal House of Bourbon. 
>   Mexican Vanilla: Made from the same Vanilla planifolia orchid as the
>   Bourbon vanillas, the Mexican vanilla flavor is lightly smokey and not
>   as buttery as the Bourbon variety. Tahitian Vanilla: From the V.
>   tahitiensis orchid, Tahitian vanilla is a softer and more perfumey
>   with a strong floral note that makes it preferred by pastry chefs for
>   subtle applications. This is the one you reach for when you want your
>   tasters to be puzzled and pleased Ugandan Vanilla: Also grown from a
>   variety of V. planifolia, the Ugandan beans are consider the world’s
>   most potent and provide an additional tone of chocolate from the dark
>   leathery bean.  Vanilla beans can be added straight to a fermenter
>   after fermentation is complete.  Split the beans lengthwise and use a
>   knife to scrape out all the gooey goodness inside.  That’s where most
>   of the flavor comes from.  Add that to the fermenter, than coarsely
>   chop up the pod and add that, too.  Start tasting after about 5 days
>   to see if you have level of vanilla you want.  The vanilla flavor and
>   aroma fades sooner than a lot of other beer flavors, so you may want
>   to let it get a little stronger than you think is needed so that in a
>   few weeks the flavor will be right.   The number of beans to use will
>   depend on the size and quality of the beans, the amount of vanilla
>   character you want, and the base beer.  2 beans per 5 gallons is a
>   good place to start. Vanilla extract can be added directly at
>   packaging using the titration process described above for coffee. Oh
>   and the best vanilla extract you can use? Homemade with the tincture
>   recipe using the best beans you can find. One thing Drew keeps on his
>   shelf is a collection of 3 different types of vanilla – Bourbon,
>   Mexican and Tahitian. Each of the bean types offers a different flavor
>   profile that you can use to generate a different effect. Even better,
>   you can blend them in different ratios to achieve a different effect.
>   Imagine a Belgian Tripel spiced with a touch of Ugandan and a big
>   splash of Tahitian. With a cool ferment you’d end up with a barely
>   vanilla and chocolate cake topped with flowers. If that doesn’t say
>   special occasion what does?

Here's the titration technique referred to...

> Pour 4 2 oz. samples of the beer (before adding your priming if you’re
>   bottling).  Add a different, measured dose of the flavoring to each
>   sample and taste critically.  Maybe even have someone else taste, too,
>   so you can find a consensus amount.  Then scale the amount of
>   flavoring in the sample you prefer up to the size of your entire batch